# Counting records for the current week

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have my database table that has a unix timestamp column called date. I'm trying to grab the information for the current week counted per day for the current week for example

Mon: 21
Tue: 0
Wed: 3
Thur: 8
Fri: 0 
Sat: 0
Sun: 0

I know how to get information for the last 7 days however I need this to show for the current week only so if today is monday then tuesday will show no data as tuesday has not come around yet.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: when its Monday you need to show zero for the remaining of the week?

Comment: If the current date is monday tue/wed etc should show nothing as the date has not yet passed.

Comment: Can you please post your db structure with dummy data?

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

**SQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE YEARWEEK(reg_date) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to get any results this is what I used 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registrations WHERE YEARWEEK(dateline) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Answer (score 0):

Try this;)

```
SELECT dayInWeek, SUM(cnt) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(dateline, '%a') AS dayInWeek,
        COUNT(1) AS cnt,
        WEEKDAY(dateline) AS idx
    FROM registrations
    WHERE WEEK(dateline, 1) = WEEK(NOW(), 1) GROUP BY WEEKDAY(dateline)
    UNION SELECT 'Mon' AS dayInWeek, 0 AS cnt, 0 AS idx
    UNION SELECT 'Tue' AS dayInWeek, 0 AS cnt, 1 AS idx
    UNION SELECT 'Wed' AS dayInWeek, 0 AS cnt, 2 AS idx
    UNION SELECT 'Thu' AS dayInWeek, 0 AS cnt, 3 AS idx
    UNION SELECT 'Fri' AS dayInWeek, 0 AS cnt, 4 AS idx
    UNION SELECT 'Sat' AS dayInWeek, 0 AS cnt, 5 AS idx
    UNION SELECT 'Sun' AS dayInWeek, 0 AS cnt, 6 AS idx) TMP
GROUP BY dayInWeek
ORDER BY idx
```